# How do we compile images with a "Build Action" of "Content" instead of the default "Resource"

Tags: jquery-ui, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing my first app in windows phone gap. It running but I am not able to see the jquery mobile data-icons.

```
<div data-role="page" id ="pichartimg">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
          <h3>Pie Chart</h3>
          <a href="#mypanel" id="bars-button" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div id='canvasDivpie' class = "sidebar"></div>
 </div>
```

I have added all the js files also,

CSS:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Please help me how to get the icon in my page header. Also how to compile images with a "Build Action" of "Content" instead of the default "Resource"

Comment: Bro, do you even check the Properties window?

Comment: No, This is my first project. Can you please explain me what can I do to get the data-icons and display images

Comment: Right cilck, properties, build action.  Please try searching before asking.